# Alternative spawning method to a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d, 2d-games

I am making a reaction game with a parallax scrolling ground. My enemy spawning timer is located in the didMoveToView and now comes my problem. The game speeds up while playing, but my spawning method stays the same, so its kind of boring if the enemys are spawned with the same frequency.
Here is the code:

```
//inside the didMoveToView    
SKAction *addEnemRand = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addRandomEnemy) onTarget:self];
SKAction *addEnemRandWait = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];
SKAction *addEnemRandAll = [SKAction sequence:@[addEnemRandWait, addEnemRand]];
SKAction *addEnemRandAllForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:addEnemRandAll];
[self runAction:addEnemRandAllForever];
```

Does someone know a way to spawn the enemys in a proper manner ?

Here is the code for moving the ground (there are two). Maybe its possible to relate the spawning speed with the position of the ground ?:

```
-(void)addGround:(SKSpriteNode *)sprite withSpeed:(int)speed {

if (ground.position.x+ground.frame.size.width/2 < 0) {

    ground.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width+ground.size.width/2, ground.size.height/2+1);
}

// movement
ground.position = CGPointMake(ground.position.x-speed, ground.position.y);    
}
```

Thanks for the help ! (code in objective c please)

EDIT: So it seems GamePlayKit can help me but I have no idea how to implement the spawning method with it. I read some tutorials in the internet but it didn't helped me. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think its worth looking into the [randomizing that GamePlayKit provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/RandomSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH9-SW1) to do this.

Take a look at this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-gameplaykit-part-3--cms-24611) where you implement a "basic rule system in combination with another random distribution to handle the respawning behaviour of enemies"

Comment: That was definitely a good read, but didn't help me regarding my question relating the spawning to the ground movement for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can either manage the spawn time using the ground position, or using the time, since the level has been started. That's my code in update method for simular task, using the time passed.

properties in initWithSize method:

```
self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = 0;
self.timeSinceEnemyAdded = 0;
self.addEnemyTimeInterval = 1.5;
self.totalGameTime = 0;
```

Update method:

```
   -(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {

        if (self.lastUpdateTimeInterval ) {
            self.timeSinceEnemyAdded += currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
            self.totalGameTime += currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;     
        }

        if (self.timeSinceEnemyAdded > self.addEnemyTimeInterval && !self.gameOver) {
            [self addEnemy];
            self.timeSinceEnemyAdded = 0;
        }

        self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;

        if (self.totalGameTime > 480) {
            self.addEnemyTimeInterval = 0.5;
            self.minSpeed = -160;
        } else if (self.totalGameTime > 240) {

            self.addEnemyTimeInterval = 0.65;
            self.minSpeed = -150;  
        } else {

        //Something else

        }
}
```

You can just manage the ground lenght property, if you want

Comment: I was looking for a spawning method without time. Can you give me an example for a spawning method using the ground position ?

Comment: In your addGround method store the "ground" in private property "self.ground.position = CGPointMake..." and use that property in update method, where istead of time, check for "if (self.ground.position > someNumber) then {self.speed = some Speed}"(You need to also make the speed variable - private property, to change it)

Comment: Can I say if (self.ground.position > someNumber) then spawn enemy ?

Comment: it works but it doesn't stop to spawn then, how can I regulate the spawning ? I mean how can it only spawn one time and then wait again ?

Comment: Then try to use code, which i posted earlier, you need the only 2 first if statements, where you calculate the time, since last enemy was added.

Comment: Or just give link to your project, if you dont know how to do that